# Sort data in Single column on the table based on the Heading in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, sorting

What I am working on is to perform sort operation in a table on a single or multiple columns. Let's assume that we have a table like this.

[image]

On clicking on Heading 1 only the Data 1 and Data 2 should be sorted when clicking on the Heading 2 the Data 3 and Data 4 need to be sorted.

Have implemented simple sort for the table in Angular, but cannot get an idea how to implement this one with two sets of data in a single column.

Even tried separate tables since the order by in Angular is based on the key in the array, both(Data 1,2,3 & 4) are getting updated when clicking on the Heading 1.

ng-repeat is used to form the table

Can anyone point me in the right direction(on Angular 1.x)?

`Sample Fiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/ANEA6/13/

Comment: If you post your HTML it will be easier to help

Comment: ^^ and the javascript as well.

Comment: Provide some code to know actual status of your code

Comment: Have added the fiddle @TonySamperi and others

Comment: Ok I'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same variable to handle the reverse!

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table class="table">
    <tr class="heading">
      <td ng-click="reverse1=!reverse1;predicate1='id'">id</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:predicate1:reverse1">
      <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="heading">
      <td ng-click="reverse2=!reverse2;predicate2='id'">id</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:predicate2:reverse2">
      <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You can check this working fiddle ==> http://jsfiddle.net/ANEA6/17/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a separate scope variable for each `<tr>` where there is `id` inside the `<td>` like this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table class="table">
      <tr><td ng-click="reverse1=!reverse1;predicate1='id'">id</td></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:predicate1:reverse1">
          <td>{{user.id}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td ng-click="reverse2=!reverse2;predicate2='id'">id</td></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:predicate2:reverse2">
          <td>{{user.id}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {id:1},
        {id:2}

    ]
}
```

This should work in your case as i do not see the `<td>` with `id` being generated dynamically. It is hard coded to two rows with `id`. The other `<tr>` following the id `<tr>` are dynamically generated using `ng-repeat` so this should be fine.

For your simplicity here is the working link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4c38w7p0/)

Comment: This is a coincidence that we both have same variable name. I have not copied yours. Its the same time we posted.